# Is there any way to configure the ios version required for your app?

Tags: ios, app-store

My first app was launched in the app-store today, requiring ios 4.2 minimum. It is a simple app without any calls to camera other "advanced" functions.

Us there anyway to allow old iphones to download it? I'm sure even version ios 2.0 will be good enough.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the `deployment target` in the build settings.

But I wouldn't change it without testing on a device with that version. There is a lot of stuff that was added in later versions.

And if you came to iOS programming after iphone OS3 was released there is a high chance you are using calls that were not available for 2.0 without even knowing it.